# OpenDKIM reports "signing table references unknown key" (CentOS 8)

Tags: centos, postfix, opendkim

I'm attempting to configure OpenDKIM with PostFix on CentOS 8.

I've set the following in `/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```
PidFile /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
Mode    sv
Syslog  yes
SyslogSuccess   yes
LogWhy  yes
UserID  opendkim:opendkim
Socket  inet:8891@localhost
Umask   002
SendReports     yes
SoftwareHeader  yes
Canonicalization        relaxed/relaxed
Selector        default
KeyTable        /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
OversignHeaders From
```

My `/etc/opendkim/KeyTable` file is as follow:

```
mta1._domainkey.esfs.info     esfs.info:mta1:/etc/opendkim/keys/esfs.info/mta1.private
```

**[Edit]**

My `/etc/opendkim/SigningTable` file contains:

```
*@esfs.info default._domainkey.esfs.info
```

**[/Edit]**

My `/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts` file is:

```
127.0.0.1
::1
*.esfs.info
```

I've generated my domain key with the following command:

```
sudo opendkim-genkey -b 2048 -d your-domain.com -D /etc/opendkim/keys/your-domain.com -s mta1 -v
```

I copied the contents of `/etc/opendkim/keys/esfs.info/mta1.txt`, into my dns entry.

However, when I test the key I get a warning that it's not secure:

```
$ sudo opendkim-testkey -d esfs.info -s mta1 -vvv
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'mta1._domainkey.esfs.info'
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK
```

When I check the server status, I get the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl status opendkim
● opendkim.service - DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-02-08 23:15:12 GMT; 5 days ago
     Docs: man:opendkim(8)
           man:opendkim.conf(5)
           man:opendkim-genkey(8)
           man:opendkim-genzone(8)
           man:opendkim-testadsp(8)
           man:opendkim-testkey
           http://www.opendkim.org/docs.html
 Main PID: 80340 (opendkim)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4947)
   Memory: 2.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/opendkim.service
           └─80340 /usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -P /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid

Feb 14 12:57:17 wp2.lostcarpark.com opendkim[80340]: CA0EC5E150: signing table references unknown key 'default._domainkey.esfs.info'
Feb 14 12:57:17 wp2.lostcarpark.com opendkim[80340]: CB0C55E150: signing table references unknown key 'default._domainkey.esfs.info'
Feb 14 12:57:17 wp2.lostcarpark.com opendkim[80340]: CBF885E150: signing table references unknown key 'default._domainkey.esfs.info'
Feb 14 12:57:17 wp2.lostcarpark.com opendkim[80340]: CCDDA5E150: signing table references unknown key 'default._domainkey.esfs.info'
```

The following is from `/var/log/maillog`:

```
Feb 14 14:52:24 wp2 postfix/pickup[279532]: warning: 374135E150: message has been queued for 1 days
Feb 14 14:52:24 wp2 postfix/pickup[279532]: 374135E150: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 14 14:52:24 wp2 postfix/cleanup[279857]: 374135E150: message-id=<20210214145224.374135E150@esfs.info>
Feb 14 14:52:24 wp2 opendkim[80340]: 374135E150: signing table references unknown key 'default._domainkey.esfs.info'
Feb 14 14:52:24 wp2 postfix/cleanup[279857]: 374135E150: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; from=<root@esfs.info> to=<root@esfs.info>
```

Hope the above is helpful in disgnosing the problem. Really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you also add the content of SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at:

```
dig default._domainkey.esfs.info. txt +short
```

This returns empty, which is unexpected. Instead you have it under a different name `mta1`:

```
dig mta1._domainkey.esfs.info txt +short
"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; " "p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzPW/qEl5jIpReXwxZ8WaS07dn3QLwa4/OWFn17bh84SM0ac7jMvo8jbBmotuO0o0oFeoODPFEYUyvXx0TScrkhycRuKqlhraBNOiPiLgRgP9L0/5Z4VdWdAhASgFMfa4mK7lfuZ85dMdyshp/SN9R3zNOvExEtuHNvQ0eUkTBcuY4UneAHhlx5SlRORdSzq02eCsgEskMLzBd7" "tEJargXaRjSLdMLnML8yJVtDHhPBH/G8AJsOWOPoXDyt6vI0pWW1o6A7BEleXYouYlge4w6S2Kgzv+QSBJoLxlCyNDo1kBG2lag5Jos4BjlahIYh1gzI5aDozG5VlVeLAq3B7QMQIDAQAB"
```

Comment: Ah, I had `default` instead of `mta1` in `/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`. Correcting that has fixed it.